# Can I remove multiple games from steam's wishlist at once?

Tags: steam

I've got a wishlist with more than 2200 titles. Even opening it is painful and slow. Removing by one reloads the whole page each time. Is there a way to do it faster?

Answer (score 4):

The browser plugin [Enhanced Steam](http://www.enhancedsteam.com/) allows you to empty your wishlist with one click.

Once the extension is installed, go to Store > Wishlist. Scroll down to the bottom of the page, where you'll find a red button labeled 'Empty wishlist'.

Comment: Nowadays Enhanced Steam is gone, the spiritual successor is Augmented Steam (see my answer below)

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays Enhanced Steam is gone, the spiritual successor is [Augmented Steam](https://augmentedsteam.com/) .

Once the extension is installed, go to Store > Wishlist. You'll find a red button labeled 'Empty wishlist'.

Comment: In a comment the OP mentions they don't want to remove all games, but since this is not mentioned in their question this is a good and helpful answer.

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

There's no way to do so, as there's no way to select multiple items in the wishlist.

Comment: Wow, Google is practically *crawling* with posts about people clamoring for this feature.  Can't believe they haven't come up with a solution for it yet.

Comment: Found [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/3krb8t/option_to_clear_my_entire_wishlist_or_a_script/) suggesting a browser extension that adds the feature to **clear the wishlist**. Tested it with Opera and Chrome but I can't find this said feature anywhere.

Comment: Lucas, It's called "Enhanced Steam". It really has the feature "clear all". I need to remove specific games but not all.